# Files saving to tmp folder on OSX when running file upload locally in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, express, unix

I have an Angular 5 app running with a file upload implemented with ngx-uploader and an express.js backend. The uploader runs, but it is putting the files *not* in the directory I have specified, but in the tmp folder on the root of my startup drive. The ExpressJS backend is running from a subfolder within my home directory on OS X (Sierra 10.12.6).

ExpressJS code:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require("cors");
var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();

app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
}));

app.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
  res.send('<html><head></head><body>\
               <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">\
                <input type="text" name="textfield"><br />\
                <input type="file" name="filefield"><br />\
                <input type="submit">\
              </form>\
            </body></html>');
  res.end();
});

const upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads/',
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, `${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}${ext}`);
    }
  })
});

app.post('/upload', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.json, upload.any());
  res.json(req.files.map(file => {
    console.log(file);
    let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    return {
      originalName: file.originalname,
      filename: file.filename
    }
  }));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('ngx-uploader server running on port 3000.');
});
```

I'm assuming this is due to some default behavior of OS X or Unix. What do I need to do to get this storing files in the directory I have specified? I'm guessing the has to do with running the app within my home directory. Then where is the a proper place to run code like this?

Comment: I assume from reading "If you want more control over your uploads, you'll want to use the storage option instead of dest. Multer ships with storage engines DiskStorage and MemoryStorage". that if the `storage` option is set `dest` has no efect.

Comment: In the docs you can find how to set the destination with diskStorage: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to declare your `upload` as follows:

```
const upload = multer({
  // ommit dest field - it is useless while using storage
  storage: multer.diskStorage({

    destination: req, file, cb) => { // you are missing this one
      cb(null, '/uploads') 
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, `${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}${ext}`);
    }

  })
});
```

From docs: `storage` has higher priority than `dest`. [image]

Further read from [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage):

> There are two options available, `destination` and `filename`. They are both functions that determine where the file should be stored. `destination` is used to determine within which folder the uploaded files should be stored. This can also be given as a string (e.g. '/tmp/uploads'). If no `destination` is given, the operating system's default directory for temporary files is used.

Which describes your case: you didn't provide `destination` and the default OS directory was used.